# How to kill 'invisible' process running on port

Tags: linux, unix, glassfish, port, kill-process

On a linux machine, am trying to start Glassfish server.

```
./startserv
```

This returns the following message:

```
There is a process already running using the admin port 4848 -- it is probably another instance of a Glassfish server
```

Have tried to identify which process this is with the following command:

```
lsof -t -i tcp:4848
```

On another machine on which Glassfish is running, this command returns the process id used by Glassfish. However, on the machine on which we are having the issue, nothing is returned.

What is the best way to identify and kill the process using port 4848, given that the `lsof -t -i tcp:4848` is not helping?

Thanks

Comment: This might help you out: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/106562/342070

Comment: Try ss -lnp | grep 4848

Comment: Tried  ss -lnp | grep 4848 - also returns nothing, it does work on the sever on which Glassfish is already running

Answer (score 1):

Try to run as root:

`netstat -tlenp | grep ':4848'`

In last column you have pid/name of process listening on port.
Now you should be able to kill process identified by pid.

https://explainshell.com/explain?cmd=netstat+-tlenp