# Trying to automatically rebuild and restart .NET console application on linux

Tags: c#, .net, linux, build, restart

I'm making a small webserver .NET console application on my windows machine that will run on a linux server (amazon os), and I'd like to make it automatically update itself when I push new code to github.

Automatically pulling from github already works by waiting for a webhook and then creating a `Process` which, as I understand it, practically lets me run a command line from the code.

```cs
using System.Diagnostics;

public static class GitApi
{
    public static void Pull(string path)
    {
        Process process = new Process()
        {
            StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo()
                {
                FileName = "git",
                Arguments = "pull",
                UseShellExecute = false,
                RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                WorkingDirectory = path
            }
        };
        process.Start();
    }
}
```

What I'd then like to do is to automatically rebuild and restart after pulling from git, by using the `dotnet run` command in a similar way.

```cs
using System.Diagnostics;

public static class Restarter
{
    public static void Restart(string path)
    {
        Process process = new Process()
        {
            StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo()
            {
                FileName = "dotnet",
                Arguments = "run",
                UseShellExecute = false,
                WorkingDirectory = path
            }
        };
        process.Start();
        Environment.Exit(0);
    }
}
```

While this *seems* to work fine on windows, when I try on linux it seems to exit the main process and then start the new one in the background somehow. It still writes in the same screen, but I can't kill it with `Ctrl + C`. Instead I have to [find the process by checking the port that it's using](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67702583/13347795) and then use the `kill` command.

Could I fix this somehow or is there another simple way to rebuild and restart a .NET console application?